# Question about relative singular homology groups

Tags: analysis, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I know that the sphere $S^{\infty}$ is contractible, but why if $H$ is a Hilbert space then we have $$H_q(H,S^{\infty})=0, q\in \mathbb{N}?$$

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried writing out the long exact sequence associated to relative homology?

Comment: with the exact sequence can i prove in general that if $A$ is contractil and $X$ a topological space, $A\subset X$ than $H_q(X,A)\sim0$?

Comment: As I said, try writing out the sequence (use reduced homology for ease of calculation at $q=0$).

Comment: i don't want to use reduced homology! and i want to find this result ! it's possible ?

Comment: Then... don't use reduced homology (it would just make your life easier but it's only a slight modification). Yes it is possible, all you need to do is *write the long exact sequence*.

Comment: ok thank you i will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We have a long exact sequence given as

$$\begin{array}{r}\cdots \to H_n(S^{\infty}) \to H_n(H) \to H_n (H,S^{\infty}) \stackrel{\delta}{\to} H_{n-1}(S^{\infty})  \to \cdots\\
\cdots\to \tilde{H}_0(S^{\infty}) \to \tilde{H}_0(H) \to H_0 (H,S^{\infty}) \to 0\end{array}$$

What does this reduce to after using the fact that $S^{\infty}$ and all Hilbert spaces are contractible?

Comment: why all hilbert space is contractible ????

Comment: All topological real/complex vector spaces are contractible by the homotopy $f_t(x)=(1-t)x$.

Comment: ah ok, so H is contractible then i know that if X and A are contractible then H_q(X,A)=0 i don't have problem with this, where i can found this propertie of spaces ? please

Comment: just tel me why $f_t(x)=(1-t)x$is a homotopy between a vector space and a point $x$ ?

Comment: $f_t$ is a homotopy between the identity map on $H$ and the constant map $c(x)=0$.